# Add push notifications to react native application

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

I have an issue when i try to add push notifications to my app.

when i see the documentation: [documentation](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) , it tells me to add some code to `android/build.gradle`, `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and others which i don't have in my application .

I am using Expo  so i don't have a folder for android and another for Ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using Expo managed workflow. You can read more about it here.
https://docs.expo.io/introduction/managed-vs-bare/
But that is why you cannot find those files you are looking for.

To help with your issue, I did find this,
https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/overview/
I tested the snack and it works. So you will have to figure out your trigger for the notification.

However I am not sure if you will be able to send the notification when the app is closed, so you will have to figure that out if needed.